# Installing file in parent directory using scons

Tags: python, installation, scons

After my build is finished, I want to copy the file to another directory. It works fine for child directories, e.g.

```
Install("temp", "test_file.txt")
```

where `temp` is the name of the child directory and `test_file.txt` is file I want to copy. But I haven't been able to do so for parent directories. Here's my MnWE `SConstruct` file:

```
Install("..\\temp", "test_file.txt")
```

Note that I am using Windows 10 in case it matters.

I have found some [information in the docs](https://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user/ch11.html), but I am unable to translate it to a working example on my machine.

Comment: And you are following the advice in the link that you gave? Be aware that you are trying to install/update a target outside the normal build hierarchy, so you have to call *SCons* with a specific target, or use an *Alias*. Please extend your question by the command line that you use to invoke *SCons* and the verbatim output of the build process for your MWE.

Comment: You might also want to have a quick look at [#2 of our "most-frequently asked" FAQs](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-install-files-the-install-method-doesnt-do-anything-in-general-how-do-i-build-anything-outside-my-current-directory).

Comment: @dirkbaechle Thanks a lot! The _Alias_ (#4) is what I was looking for although #2 also worked. I don't know why I was unable to find the FAQ by googling.

Comment: If you have concrete ideas about making this info more "searchable", let us know in our User mailing list. We have tons of tips and documentation, sometimes the hard part is to put them where the user expects to find results with her first search command. ;)